# My parrot has a milky-type appearance in only one eye, and he can't see out of it

Tags: parrots

One of my parrot's eyes appears partially milky and he is unable to see from that eye. The other eye is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like your parrot has a cataract in his eye. Basically, it's a decrease in opacity of the lens in the eye, which appears like a milky white cloud, that can lead to decreased vision or blindness.

Usually this is a sign of age, but that typically means in both eyes. If it's just the one, there *could* be additional health concerns. In either case, seeing a vet that has avian experience is simply a good idea here. There's really no treatment for cataracts (though surgical lens removal is a possibility), but if the cause is something other than age, you want to stop it before the other eye is affected.

As a note, a bird can still lead a good and happy life when blind, it's obviously just a bit more work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @John Cavan, My Parrot is not old, i will go to bird hospital